# Header dose not appearing when using a drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am overlapping a StackNavigator on a DrawerNavigator. This is my code

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: WelcomeContainer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft:
       <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Icon name="menu" color='#5c72b0' size={35} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingRight:80 }} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') } />
      <ChangeLanguage style={{ margin: 30 , padding: 30}} />
      </View>,
      headerRight: 
      <HeaderUserInformation />,
    })
  },
  Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
},
  About: {
  screen: About,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
})



const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen:StackNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: WelcomeContainer,
        navigationOptions: {
        }
      }
    })
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      Category: {
        screen: SettingsContainer,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Settings"
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

The drawer works properly but there is a problem with the header. This was not the case before I embed the StackNavigator on the DrawerNavigator. The problem is that I customized the header by adding buttons and I am not seeing them anymore on the header. And When I navigate to a new Screen I am not seeing the back button on the header anymore. Do you have an idea what could the problem be?